# use BLE to open door in background iOS

Tags: ios

My app uses BLE to open the door lock

When the app is connected to the device, the device is occupied by me, and other phones will not be able to connect to the device, so I repeatedly scan the same device, use RSSI to determine the distance, when I am close to the device and then connect and open the door command, away from the device Interrupt connection

However, the background cannot scan the same device repeatedly, only once, and it will not meet the RSSI close to the door, so it will not be connected. Is there any solution?

Another way,If app in the background, I will connect and update the RSSI immediately after scanning, and the App can only read for 10 seconds. If the user closes the door after more than ten seconds, it will not open.

Comment: did you check background mode supported by iOS app. https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html, check the Communicating with an External Accessory section if your lock can deliver updates. If not, you may try to enable background location usage to make the app not suspended.